# blueimp file upload vb.net no thumbnail showing

Tags: jquery, vb.net, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I have a problem using blueimp file upload in vb.net. I implemented it that way:

```
sb.Append("<div id='fileupload'>" & _
                    "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" & _
                        "<div class='fileupload-buttonbar'>" & _
                            "<label class='fileinput-button'>" & _
                                "<span>Add files...</span>" & _
                                "<input id='file' type='file' name='files[]' multiple>" & _
                            "</label>" & _
                            "<button type='submit' class='start'>Start upload</button>" & _
                            "<button type='reset' class='cancel'>Cancel upload</button>" & _
                            "<button type='button' class='delete'>Delete files</button>" & _
                        "</div>" & _
                    "</form>" & _
                    "<div class='fileupload-content'>" & _
                        "<table class='files'></table>" & _
                        "<div class='fileupload-progressbar'></div>" & _
                    "</div>" & _
                "</div>")
```

All fileupload.js'es are linked well. 
But after selecting a file no thumbnail is shown. I tried using that asp.net example from [here](http://www.webtrendset.com/2011/06/22/complete-code-example-for-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-control-in-asp-net/).

When I call the index.html everything goes well. If I try using it within my vb.net project no thumbnail is shown.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Edit:** My source looks like this:

```
    <div id="fileupload">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <label class="fileinput-button"><span>Add files...</span>
        <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple=""></label>
        <button type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
        <button type="reset" class="cancel">Cancel upload</button>
        <button type="button" class="delete">Delete files</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="fileupload-content">
        <table class="files"></table><div class="fileupload-progressbar">
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**Edit 2:** It seems like something overrides the "add" function. If I use the example index.html from downloaded .zip I can console.log the add. In my vb.net project I cant... Does someone has an idea how to find out which file is overriding that one?

Comment: how can that code run in vb.net? It isn't vb.net code

Comment: @ArwinZhang ?Confused?  Looks like VB.Net to me - `StringBuilder.Append()` and the use of `& _`

Comment: I never look of kind of this code before in vb.net, like <div></div>, it's just like web programming. You are using this code for what in vb.net? I wasn't understand of your question until now

Comment: We need to see more code - you've only supplied us with some generated code that you are probably writing with `Response.Write()`.  Can you show us the rendered code instead?  (Use View Source and show us that :))

Comment: I have edited my post. And yes you are right sir, I use StringBuilder.Append(). It seems like there is no uploadTemplate used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now!

The problem was that this reference was not working for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
```

With this one it works like a charm:

```
downloadTemplate: function (o) {
            var rows = $();
            $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
                var row = $('<tr class="template-download fade">' +
                (file.error ? '<td></td><td class="name"></td>' +
                    '<td class="size"></td><td class="error" colspan="2"></td>' :
                        '<td class="preview"></td>' +
                            '<td class="name"><a></a></td>' +
                            '<td class="size"></td><td colspan="2"></td>'
                ) + '<td class="delete"><button>Delete</button> ' +
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1"></td></tr>');
                row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
                if (file.error) {
                    row.find('.name').text(file.name);
                    row.find('.error').text(
                    locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error
                );
                } else {
                    row.find('.name a').text(file.name);
                    if (file.thumbnail_url) {
                        row.find('.preview').append('<a><img></a>')
                        .find('img').prop('src', file.thumbnail_url);
                        row.find('a').prop('rel', 'gallery');
                    }
                    row.find('a').prop('href', file.url);
                    row.find('.delete button')
                    .attr('data-type', file.delete_type)
                    .attr('data-url', file.delete_url);
                }
                rows = rows.add(row);
            });
            return rows;
        }
```